# Attachment uploaded trigger to send an email to Opportunity

Tags: email, attachment

I use ccScan to scan certificates to Salesforce as an attachment to the matching Opportunity.

But now I need to send an email to that Opportunity once the certificate gets attached. This cannot be something that runs on a daily basis at a fixed time. It has to be triggered by the uploading action!

Is this possible? If so, how can I achieve this?

A swift response is much appreciated!

Comment: A trigger on attachment should get you what you need.

Comment: Yes! But where can I find such a trigger. Is there one?

Comment: You will have to write it or pay someone to write it....You can start by learning about triggers on salesforce's trailhead site

Comment: You can also try using the Search function at the top right of this page to look for posts that might provide the content you're looking for. Also look to the right of this page where you'll see "Related" which is a list of posts that "might" be related to your question. Google can also be your best friend along with this search engine: http://findsf.info/

Comment: Hi guys, thank you very much for the suggestions. 

But I am determined to write the trigger myself. I found a similar question which gives me some idea of how to proceed. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/78306/trigger-on-attachment-to-insert-feeditem

Am I on the right path here?

Comment: @Isuru - That code will just confuse you if you are just starting as much of it is irrelevant to what you are trying to do, not to mention it does not work as per the OP questions....See answer below to get you started

Comment: @Eric - Yes. It did confuse me at first. But I am a little familiar with Java, so the object creation and method calling parts were noticeable. And I read numerous online articles. But your main answer hit the spot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you started Your trigger would look something like this:

```
trigger myTrigger on Attachment(After Insert){

//Holds opportunities to update with trigger to send email
Map<ID, Opportunity> oppsTBU = New Map<ID,Opportunity>();

    for(Attachment a : trigger.new){
       if(a.parentID.getsObjectType() == Opportunity.sObjecttype){
             //Check if this attachment name matches the one you want to trigger the email
             if(a.Name == '<NAMEOFATTACHMENT>')
                 oppsTBU.put(a.parentID,New Opportunity(id=a.parentID, EMAILSENDFLAGFIELD = true); //Set checkbox to fire workflow to send email
       }
    }

   update oppsTBU.values();

}
```

Then you can have a workflow to send the email and uncheck the email flag field (that you need to create)....

Comment: n.b. if two attachments for same oppo arrive in same batch, only one email will be sent. This is most likely "just fine" but worth pointing out to OP

Comment: Wow Eric! Thanks a lot! I got the first two lines down by myself (for loop part and if condition) but was struggling with the actual email sending flag part. This should be more than enough to get me running. I deeply appreciate all the help. Writing the class should not be too difficult. Will attempt it myself.